# Last iteration of for loop not outputting

Tags: java, for-loop

Forgive me if this is not formatted properly, this is my first post. I looked to see if this issue has been found before and I cannot find anyone who has had the same problem I am having.

I am trying to learn Java and cannot for the life of me figure out why my for loops are not outputting the last iteration. I am going through codeabbey's exercises and completed the first two relatively easily. However on the third and fourth problems, I cant get my for loop to output during the last iteration.

I began looking on google and thought I would compare my answer to someone else's. I couldn't see why mine wouldn't work when my code was almost identical to the person I found. So I copied their code and to my surprise I had the same problem when this code also would not output on the last iteration.

So, here is the context.

The website gives you a single number first which is the number of sets of the following numbers. For the third problem, you are to add the sets of two, output the sum followed by a space and loop through the entire batch. For the fourth problem, it is similar where the first number is the number of sets in the batch but you are to compare the two numbers and output the lower number. I will copy my code here for the third problem because the code is simpler.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Summation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){

            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();

            System.out.println(a + b + " ");
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the input you are to copy and paste:

3

100 8

15 245

1945 54

and this is my output:

108 260

So, as you can see we are missing the last output here. I tried changing the for loop to `(i < (n+1) )` which still didn't change anything. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Try `for(int i = 0; i <= n;i++)`

Comment: Man that is hard to debug - I'm not even going to try! Start by making each output on a different line (use `System.out.println`) and include the value of `i` on each line so at least we have a chance to figure out what goes where...

Comment: works fine for me when I used `3` `12` `34` -> `46` `1` `2` -> `3` `5` `6` -> `11`

Comment: Works fine for me too.

Comment: @ScaryWombat That is a great example of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve If you can show an issue with 3 values instead of 15 it makes it a lot easier for everyone to get a handle on the issue and help. - OP take note!

Comment: I am guessing since you are printing in the same line. somehow your console is cutting the last output. can you try System.out.println instead of System.out.print so that you see all in different lines.

Comment: @John3136 I am lazy too ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys and I apologize for the long example, I will edit my post now. I still get the exact same problem with a shorter example, and I also tried what @i_am_zero suggested by making i<=n and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I tested it, and with your numbers, typing them in one by one it works.  Copy pasting them, press enter one more time at the end of the copy.  If you don't press enter, the scanner thinks you're still adding to the second number so it won't continue until enter is pressed.

Comment: This worked. I just pressed enter a second time after pasting the input and pressing enter. Any idea as to why this is and how i could prevent this in the future? Thank you so much.

Comment: I believe it's like I said above, if you don't press enter, for all the computer knows, 455583 (the number you had above) may not be finished.  It thinks you might want 45558383758435 and it wouldn't know to stop until a new line is encountered.  What you can do is if you're reading from a file in the full deployment, make sure the file (or whatever sends the numbers) ends with a new line character, similar to how there's a new line between the first set of numbers and the second.

Comment: So in the original test (that failed), did the computer program end or was it still waiting for input ?

Comment: It was still waiting for input, it ended when you pressed enter.

Answer (score -1):

I would try using println() as someone else suggested, or calling flush() at the end of the program to make sure something isn't being held in a buffer and not being written.

Comment: I read before that auto flush was env specific and not necessarily true for all environments. I think if the println() fixes the problem then its possibly because of same.